# Receipt Printer Adds Huge White Space At Top Of Receipt

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing

I have a [Star TSP143 LAN printer](https://www.starmicronics.com/pages/TSP100). When I print a PDF from a Windows machine, the printer adds a large amount of paper (a couple feet) before the contents of the pdf. I don't know why. When I print a word document it is fine.

I can see in the print preview that the white space is added. I don't know how to stop this.

I have set the print prefferences to 72mm x 200mm but there is still a couple inches of whitespace at the top depending on how long the receipt is.

[image]

Comment: It would seem to me that the PDF is 7.88" high. Maybe you could attach a sample (or upload to e.g. dropbox)?